# Determine the truth value and validity of the propositions given

Tags: logic

$P_1$: If logic or set theory are important, then students learn them.

$P_2$:Logic and calculus are important.

$P_3$: Therefore, students learn them.

Given 3 propositions above. Actually, there are 3 questions asked here: change the propositions into logical symbol, create the truth table and the truth value of the propositions, and check the validity.
I have no problem for the first one and also making the truth table. But, I have some doubt when facing: the truth value of the propositions and check the validity. After I make the truth table, how can I determine the truth value? and then what requirements needed to make premises/sentences above valid or not (how to determine its validity?)

My idea: The truth value is determined by fact/reality, is not it? 
For instance, Jakarta is the capital city of Indonesia. (true)
But, how can we make sure that everyone thinks that calculus, logic, or set theory are important?

Comment: A propositional formula is *valid* (i.e. a *tautology*) if in the corersponding column of the truth table it appears only the value TRUE.

Comment: An *argument* is valid if in every row where **all** the premises are TRUE also the conclusion is TRUE.

Comment: See [here](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/23.html) and [here](http://dsearls.org/courses/M120Concepts/ClassNotes/Logic/130A_examples.htm) for some examples of use of truth table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA -  it doesn't matter how "them" is interpreted. "Logic or set theory are important" and "students learn them" could be replaced with "All mimsy were the borogoves" and "the mome raths outgrabe" without changing the nature of this problem.